# docker-compose build env not populated in docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, gitlab-ci, rancher

Use case is to build and image and deploy to Rancher 2.5.5 with gitlab-ci.yml. Since envs couldn't be passed directly in my situation I'm trying to build-in envs to docker image with **docker-compose build** (dev/stage things is the next thing, just let's leave it for now). docker-compose **run** --env-file works, but docker-compose **build** ignores envs.

Any advice will be appreciated

P.S. if you know the way to pass envs to rancher2 container somehow from gitlab-ci it also resolves the problem

I've tried the following:

- set it in docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  testproject:
    build:
      context: .
    env_file: .env-dev
    image: example.registry/testimage:latest
```

- set it in gitlab-ci

```
variables:
     IMAGE: "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
build-image:
  stage: build
  allow_failure: false
  tags:
    - docker
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker-compose --env-file .env-dev build
    - docker-compose push
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: kpolszewski/rancher2-gitlab-deploy
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - upgrade --cluster $CLUSTER --environment $ENV --stack $NAMESPACE --service $SERVICE --new-image $IMAGE
```

- source it in Dockerfile entrypoint
- set it in .env file

nothing works

I can see new image in the registry and local (when I test it locally ) but no env inside when I run container

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set env values on the build stage, you can use build-args as follows:

```
FROM ...
ARG SOME_ARG
ENV SOME_ENV=$SOME_ARG
```

Then, in your docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  testproject:
    build:
      context: .
    args:
      SOME_ARG: "SOME_VALUE"
    env_file: .env-dev
    image: example.registry/testimage:latest
```

But think twice, are you sure you want your ENV variables be dynamically set on the build stage?